# No he podido imprimir usando C# WPF 6.0

Tags: c#, wpf

Este es mi primer proyecto con C# WPF .NET 6.0 (VS2022 Prof) que estoy desarrollando. He escrito mucho código y a esta altura me doy cuenta que no puedo usar Crystal Report, tampoco RDLC. Estoy con fuertes problemas laborales por este inconveniente. Me gustaría una ayuda con un pequeño ejemplo o algún enlace con las instrucciones adecuadas para usar RDLC. TODOS los he ejemplos que he visto no están actualizados a la versión en que estoy trabajando. En otros foros me indican que no es posible usar ni RDLC ni Crystal Report en .NET 6.0. Estaré muy agradecido que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Lamentablemente Microsoft parece que no tiene planes para soportar reporting en net core. Puedes probar con librerias de terceros,como por ejemplo https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore

Comment: Puedes crear una 2da aplicación usando la versión adecuada de .net para RDLC a modo de visor. La primera aplicación invoca a la segunda cuando sea necesario. Por otro lado yo hice hace varios reportes en formato XPS, que con WPS se llevan muy bien según tus reportes también puede ser alternativa

Comment: Hola Yussef, estoy creando en mi solución, que tengo actuálmemte, un proyecto que pueda utilizar RDLC solamente para generar los reportes que necesito. Me gustaría que me ayudaras de cómo puedo llamar desde mi proyecto principal a la ventana del proyecto correspondiente donde tengo los reportes, tengo varios días buscando un ejemplo y no encuentro nada. Gracias Pikoh por tu enlace de ejemplo. Hoy mismo voy a probar si esto me funciona. Les agradezco a ambos su tiempo.